# Can't dynamically add rows to a <TABLE> in IE?

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, cross-browser, html-table

I have an AJAX application that downloads a JSON object and uses the data to add rows to an HTML <table> using Javascript DOM functions. It works perfectly... except in Internet Explorer. IE doesn't give any sort of error, and I've verified as best as I can that the code is being executed by the browser, but it simply has no effect. I created this quick and dirty page to demonstrate the problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><title></title></head><body>

<table id="employeetable">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Job</th>
    </tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function addEmployee(employeeName, employeeJob) {
        var tableElement = document.getElementById("employeetable");
        if (tableElement) {
            var newRow = document.createElement("tr");
            var nameCell = document.createElement("td");
            var jobCell = document.createElement("td");
            nameCell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(employeeName));
            jobCell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(employeeJob));
            newRow.appendChild(nameCell);
            newRow.appendChild(jobCell);
            tableElement.appendChild(newRow);
            alert("code executed!");
        }
    }

    setTimeout("addEmployee(\"Bob Smith\", \"CEO\");", 1000);
    setTimeout("addEmployee(\"John Franks\", \"Vice President\");", 2000);
    setTimeout("addEmployee(\"Jane Doe\", \"Director of Marketing\");", 3000);
</script>

</body></html>
```

I haven't tried IE 8, but both IE 7 and IE 6 do not show the additional rows that are supposedly being added. I can't fathom why. Does anyone know a good workaround to this problem, or am I perhaps doing something wrong?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to create a TBODY element to add your new TR to and then add the TBODY to your table, like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><title></title></head><body>

<table id="employeetable">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Job</th>
    </tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function addEmployee(employeeName, employeeJob) {
        var tableElement = document.getElementById("employeetable");
        if (tableElement) {
            var newTable = document.createElement('tbody');   // New
            var newRow = document.createElement("tr");
            var nameCell = document.createElement("td");
            var jobCell = document.createElement("td");
            nameCell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(employeeName));
            jobCell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(employeeJob));
            newRow.appendChild(nameCell);
            newRow.appendChild(jobCell);
            newTable.appendChild(newRow);   // New
            tableElement.appendChild(newTable);   // New
            alert("code executed!");
        }
    }

    setTimeout("addEmployee(\"Bob Smith\", \"CEO\");", 1000);
    setTimeout("addEmployee(\"John Franks\", \"Vice President\");", 2000);
    setTimeout("addEmployee(\"Jane Doe\", \"Director of Marketing\");", 3000);
</script>

</body></html>
```

Comment: actually, `tableElement.getElementsByType('tbody')` should return what is desired here....

Comment: actually, <pre>tableElement.getElementsByType('tbody')</pre> should return what is desired here

Comment: Sorry guys, still kinda new on the comment / answer syntax differences. Obviously, wanted to put code-style formatting on the code fragment.

Comment: I realize this is an old post, but since others may still use it for reference, the above comment didn't work for me. What worked for me was `tableElement.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0]`

Comment: @Wally: I tried adding `<tbody>` in my [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/abhisheksimion/LSh4M/13/) but still it does not seem to work on IE, my [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6606523/dynamic-table-is-not-visible-in-ie-8/6606659#6606659)

Answer (score 8):

Apparently, in IE you need to append your row to the TBody element, not the Table element...
See discussion at [Ruby-Forum](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/139836).

Expanding on the discussion there, the <table> markup is generally done without explicit <thead> and <tbody> markup, but the <tbody> ELEMENT is where you actually need to add your new row, as <table> does not contain <tr> elements directly.

Comment: Appending to tbody works consistently in all browsers, so it is safe to do it always.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: now works in IE!  insertSiblingNodesAfter uses the parentNode of the sibling, which happens to be a tbody in IE

---

It's hard to know what quirks are in store when you try to manipulate the DOM cross-browser.  I'd recommend that you use an existing library that has been fully tested across all major browsers, and accounts for quirks.

Personally I use MochiKit, you can dive into DOM manipulation here:
http://mochikit.com/doc/html/MochiKit/DOM.html

Your final function might look something like this:

```
function addEmployee(employeeName, employeeJob) {
    var trs = getElementsByTagAndClassName("tr", null, "employeetable");
    insertSiblingNodesAfter(trs[trs.length-1], TR({}, TD({}, employeeName), TD({}, employeeJob));
    alert("code executed!");
}
```

Comment: +1 for using MochiKit (my fave library), but you missed the actual answer - he needs to append rows to a TBody for IE to recognize the rows.

Comment: I didn't realise that appendChildNodes wasn't working - I had been using insertSiblingNodes in my own code, which works - I've updated the answer to reflect a working solution.