# Dynamic table not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I have a dynamic table which works in firefox 4+ and chrome but does not display the table contents in Internet Explorer. What could be the problem? Here is my [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aQPZk/)

Firefox result

[image]

Internet Explorer 8 result

[image]

Please help somebody. This is the 2nd time I am posting this question. Thanks

Comment: Works on IE9 for me. Btw, why are you posting this question again? What happened to the first one?

Comment: would you please explain little bit more..what you are expecting and what not working in IE...

Comment: Can you copy your HTML code also?

Comment: @gvl Click the DEMO link

Comment: Why `appendTo('#compareContent')` and not `html('#compareContent')`

Comment: in IE8 I get 0 here `alert($(xml).find('TagResult').length)`

Comment: @mplungjan: You are right, even i get `0` for  `alert($(xml).find('TagResult').length)` in IE but `17` in firefox. What could be the problem. Also when i do `html('#compareContent')` it does not even displays the table

Comment: @bazmegakapa: In the previous version of this question, I was suggested to add `tbody` since there is compatability issues with IE and led me to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/812693/cant-dynamically-add-rows-to-a-table-in-ie) url. After this i added `<tbody>` to my code but still it did not work, and also I was getting no reply on it from past 2 days, so i deleted the question and came up with this. Please help :)

Comment: @vivek: The code is in the `demo` link

Answer (score 1):

It's problem with regard to the xml as mplungjan quoted he gets 0 in IE

So Try this `var xml=$.parseXML(dummy1);`

The [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/abhisheksimion/aQPZk/13/)

Comment: But normally xml=$('<.....>') also should work :(
See this one - still does not run in IE8 http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/fdL3B/