# how to display array values inside <table> tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I have array values like this. I want to display these values in HTML table tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var orderArray = [
    ["1","29-Aug-2012", "Product1", "client1"],
    ["2","29-Aug-2012", "Product2", "client2"],
    ["3","29-Aug-2012", "Product3", "client3"],
    ["4","29-Aug-2012", "Product4", "client4"],
    ["5","29-Aug-2012", "Product5", "client5"]
    ];

function display()
{
    for(i=0;i<ordertArray.length;i++)
    {
    //How to display values of array inside the div or table tag ???
    }
}

</script>
```

How to display values of array inside the div or table tag ???

Comment: Do you already have a table or do you need to create table on the fly?

Comment: I want to know how the value are fetched. Be it manual or on-the-fly.

Answer (score 6):

`orderArray`'s items represent `<tr>` elements, and each item inside represents a `<td>` element. So you can loop through `orderArray` creating `<tr>`s, and then loop through its elements on each loop creating `<td>`s: http://jsfiddle.net/h7F7e/.

```
var table = document.getElementById("table");  // set this to your table

var tbody = document.createElement("tbody");
table.appendChild(tbody);
orderArray.forEach(function(items) {
  var row = document.createElement("tr");
  items.forEach(function(item) {
    var cell = document.createElement("td");
    cell.textContent = item;
    row.appendChild(cell);
  });
  tbody.appendChild(row);
});
```

Comment: How to display this table inside a div on particular location ?

Comment: @Ismail Vitla: I actually assumed you already have a table. Just define the table in HTML somewhere and set `var table = ...` so that it refers to the table.

Comment: [Doesn't work for IE 8 or lower](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/812693/cant-dynamically-add-rows-to-a-table-in-ie)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this would create a dynamic table for you :

```
// get handle on div
var container = document.getElementById('container');
// create table element
var table = document.createElement('table');
var tbody = document.createElement('tbody');
// loop array
for (i = 0; i < orderArray.length; i++) {
    // get inner array
    var vals = orderArray[i];
    // create tr element
    var row = document.createElement('tr');
    // loop inner array
    for (var b = 0; b < vals.length; b++) {
        // create td element
        var cell = document.createElement('td');
        // set text
        cell.textContent = vals[b];
        // append td to tr
        row.appendChild(cell);
    }
    //append tr to tbody
    tbody.appendChild(row);
}
// append tbody to table
table.appendChild(tbody);
// append table to container
container.appendChild(table);
```

Uses [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createElement) and [`element.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.appendChild)

[Working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/QwBsa/2/)

Comment: Don't use innerHTML for text values

Comment: How to add an additional row having table headings ?

Comment: @ManseUK how to append an header row to this table ?

Answer (score 2):

Use the DOM functions of [table elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLTableElement):

```
function display() {
    var table = document.createElement("table");
    for (var i=0; i<orderArray.length; i++) {
        var row = table.insertRow();
        for (var j=0; j<orderArray[i].length; j++) {
            var cell = row.insertCell();
            cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(orderArray[i][j]));
        }
    }
    return table;
}
```

Call that function when the DOM is ready, and append the returned table somewhere.

Comment: Works perfectly but one of my `<td>` contains `<img></img>` tags which are displayed as raw text. Is there a possibility to have them in HTML ?

Comment: @Florent If you have html content (and properly xss-escaped!) instead of text, don't create a text node but use `cell.innerHTML = orderArray[i][j];`

Answer (score 1):

```
var table = "<table>"; // Open Table

for(i=0; i<orderArray.length; i++)
{
 table += "<tr>"; // Open Row

 for(i2=0; i2<orderArray[i].length; i2++) {
 {
  table += "<td>" + orderArray[i][i2] + "</td>"; // Each Column
 }

 table += "</tr>"; // Close Row
}

table += "</table>"; // Close Table
```

Comment: You're adding four cells on each inner loop - thus 16 per row in total.

Comment: The foreach syntax is not supported in most browsers