# How to convert arrays which contain HTML elements to a table in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an array of arrays which contain HTML elements like `<a>` I would like to convert to a table but my problem is that HTML is displayed as raw text.

First I supposed it was a problem with hidden double quotes so I replace them with `.replace()`

```
cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(x[i][j].replace(/"/g, "")));
```

But it looks like HTML is corretly formated in the Chrome DevTools DOM element :

```
<td><a href='http://website.org/prod4'>Product4</a></td>
```

Could you please tell me what should I do to display HTML elements in my table ?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2e0budqw/2/)

```
var orderArray = [
    ["1", "29-Aug-2012", "Product1", "client1"],
    ["2", "29-Aug-2012", "Product2", "client2"],
    ["3", "29-Aug-2012", "Product3", "client3"],
    ["4", "29-Aug-2012", "<a href='http://website.org/prod/'>Product4</a>", "client4"],
    ["5", "29-Aug-2012", "Product5", "client5"]
    ];

function display() {
    // get handle on div
    var table = document.createElement("table");
    for (var i = 0; i < orderArray.length; i++) {
        var row = table.insertRow();
        for (var j = 0; j < orderArray[i].length; j++) {
            var cell = row.insertCell();
            cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(orderArray[i][j]));
        }
    }
    return table;
}
var container = document.getElementById('container');
container.appendChild(display());
```

I use the code proposed by Bergi in this question : [how to display array values inside <table> tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12178792/how-to-display-array-values-inside-table-tag)

Thank you,

Comment: The `.createTextNode()` method does exactly what its name suggests: it makes a **text node**.  That's why the browser is ignoring your HTML markup.

Comment: ... or set `cell.innerHTML`.

Comment: The title is also a bit incorrect, as I only see a String[][] array. There's no HTML in any array man

Comment: @StephanBijzitter You should look again. There is a hyperlink in the 4th array element.

Comment: @StephanBijzitter there are some table cells with markup, like `orderArray[0][3]`

Comment: Seems like a string to me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the **[`.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)** property to solve the issue of parsing the HTML, when there is HTML and injecting the plain text when there isn't.

Additionally, you can use the **[`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)** method as an easier way to loop.

```js
var orderArray = [
    ["1", "29-Aug-2012", "Product1", "client1"],
    ["2", "29-Aug-2012", "Product2", "client2"],
    ["3", "29-Aug-2012", "Product3", "client3"],
    ["4", "29-Aug-2012", "<a href='http://website.org/prod4'>Product4</a>", "client4"],
    ["5", "29-Aug-2012", "Product5", "client5"]
];

function display() {
    // get handle on div
    var container = document.getElementById('container');
    
    var table = document.createElement("table");
    
    // Arrays support a forEach method that accepts a callback function
    // to be executed on each item of the array. This function is automatically
    // passed 3 arguments: the current array element, the current index and the array itself.
    // We only need to capture the reference to the array element (value and innerValue in
    // this example).
    orderArray.forEach(function(value) {
        var row = table.insertRow();
        
        value.forEach(function(innerValue) {
            var cell = row.insertCell();
            cell.innerHTML = innerValue;
        });
    });
    
    return table;
}

container.appendChild(display());
```

```css
td { padding:5px; }
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the `Array.forEach() ` hint, more elegant.

Comment: @Florent You're welcome. Yes, it allows us to completely remove indexes in this case.

Comment: Is there a possibility with `insertRow()` to specify whether it is a `td` or a `th` that is inserted in the `tr` ? can't find how I could declare the first array index as table header. EDIT oh I see there is `createTHead()` !

Answer (score 1):

To simplify the overall code:

```
container.innerHTML="<table>"+(orderArray.map(row=>"<tr><td>"+row.join("</td><td>")+"</td></tr>").join(""))+"</table>".
```

Comment: @ScottMarcus join?