# getJSON() in a loop in a getJSON() in a newrow ie8

Tags: jquery, html, json, internet-explorer-8

I am not an educated in JS, an for some reason I feel i am wrong in this kind of usage but, the basic idea is to query the database for a list of em;
inside the first loop for each, create a row in the table, 
follow use the value inside a JSON call as &emkey
and put the 2 numeric values from the 4 returned in each column.

```
$.getJSON(base_url+"&list=1",  function(data) {
$.each(data,function(key,value){
    var row='<tr>';
    row+='<th>'+ value+'</th>';     
    $.getJSON(base_url+"&emkey="+value,  function(data2) {
        $.each(data2,function(key,value){
                    // fix me //
            row+='<td>'+ value[1]+'</td>';
            row+='<td>'+ value[3]+'</td>';
            row+="</tr>";
        });
    });
    document.getElementById("tabledata1").innerHTML+=row;
});
});
```

first JSON Return

```
jQuery110209887605804210914_1389710560683([
['uno'],
['dos'],
['tres'],
['cuatro'],
['cinco']
]);
```

second call example (4more):

```
jQuery110209887605804210914_1389710560683([
['in',130,'out',198]
]);
```

currenlty I am geting the HTML table with every row for the group, and the firebug shows each JSON Call correctly

Comment: `$.getJSON` is *asynchronous*!  When you call `$.getJSON` it runs that AJAX call in the background, then continues with your code.  At some point in the distant future - when the AJAX call finishes - then the callback will be ran.  At that point `document.getElementById("tabledata1").innerHTML+=row;` will have already ran, so setting `row` to something won't help.  You need to do *everything* related to the AJAX call's return data in its callback.

Comment: the closure concept is wait for it.........biting me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.getJSON` is *asynchronous*!  When you call `$.getJSON` it runs that AJAX call in the background, then continues with your code.  At some point in the distant future - when the AJAX call finishes - then the callback will be ran.  At that point `document.getElementById("tabledata1").innerHTML+=row;` will have already ran, so setting `row` to something won't help.

What you can do is, wait until all the AJAX calls are done, and do something like this:

```
$.getJSON(base_url+"&list=1",  function(data) {
    var rowAJAX = [],
        rowData = [];

    $.each(data, function(key, value){
        // Fire all the ajax calls and save their promises
        rowAJAX.push($.getJSON(base_url+"&emkey="+value));
        // Also save the associated header values
        rowData.push(value);
    });

    // Wait until all the AJAX calls are done
    $.when.apply($, rowAJAX).done(function(){
        // then loop through the data return by each and build the table
        for(var i = 0, len = arguments.length; i < len; i++){
            var row = '<tr>',
                thisRow = arguments[i][0],
                header = rowData[i],

            row += '<th>'+ header +'</th>';
            $.each(thisRow, function(key2, value2){
                row += '<td>'+ value2[1]+'</td>';
                row += '<td>'+ value2[3]+'</td>';
            });
            row += "</tr>";

            document.getElementById("tabledata1").innerHTML += row;
        }
    });
});
```

This code is untested, but should hopefully give you a rough idea of the solution here.

Answer (score 0):

from my understanding... is better to not advance in the code until you get the reply from JSON...

```
$.getJSON(base_url+"&listem=1",  function(data) {
$.each(data,function(key,value){
    var row='<tr>';
    row+='<th>'+ value+'</th>';     
    $.getJSON(base_url+"&start="+d+"&emkey="+value,  function(data) {
            $.each(data,function(key,value){
                 row+='<td>'+ value[1]+'</td>';
                 row+='<td>'+ value[3]+'</td></tr>';            
                 document.getElementById("tabledata1").innerHTML+=row;
                 });
           });
    });
});
```

this new loop is creating the table, and the result is what I expected, but is drawing the table over another div.

Comment: the whole idea doesn't work on IE8 as <TR> is a readonly so no new row can be added by this method.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working on a ie8 and firefox from another answer [here in this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812693/cant-dynamically-add-rows-to-a-table-in-ie)

```
$.getJSON(base_url+"&listem=1",  function(data) {
$.each(data,function(key,value){
    var country = value;    
    $.getJSON(base_url+"&emkey="+value,  function(data) {
            $.each(data,function(key,value){
                addRow(country,value[1],value[3]);
            })
        })
    })
});
function addRow(country,totin,totout) {
        var tableElement = document.getElementById("tabledat");
        if (tableElement) {
            var newTable = document.createElement('tbody');   // New
            var newRow = document.createElement("tr");
            var newcountry = document.createElement("td");
            var newtotin = document.createElement("td");
            var newtotout= document.createElement("td");
            newcountry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(country));
            newtotin.appendChild(document.createTextNode(totin));
            newtotout.appendChild(document.createTextNode(totout));
            newRow.appendChild(newcountry);
            newRow.appendChild(newtotin);
            newRow.appendChild(newtotout);
            newTable.appendChild(newRow);   // New
            tableElement.appendChild(newTable);   // New
            //alert("code executed!");
        }
    }
})
```

alter the HTML in the ID of the table to match the id " tabledat "